# Get current alpha value for fade animation

Tags: android, animation, fadein, fadeout

I need your help for an animation on Android.

Actually I've a fade out animation on the screen with a duration = 10 seconds.

During this time, if I tap on the screen I would like launch fade in from current alpha value.

For example

t=0second I launch the fade out (fromAlpah=1.0 toAlpha=0)
t=5 seconds I tap on the screen, so I would like launch the fadeIn from the current alpha (0.5 in this example)

My problem is: I don't know how I can get the current alpha value

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435423/android-getalpha-from-animated-view/38438035#38438035