# Android - getAlpha() from Animated View

Tags: java, android, animation, alpha

I have an animation like this:

```
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
fadeOut.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
fadeOut.setDuration(350);
myView.startAnimation(fadeOut);
```

I am trying is to get its Alpha durring the Animation as such:

```
System.out.println(myView.getAlpha());
```

However, it always returns "1.0" throughout the animation. How can I obtain the actual alpha value of `myView` during the animation process?

Comment: See also using `Transformation` class to retrieve alpha directly from your `AlphaAnimation` instead of your `View` e.g. `fadeOut.getTransformation(time, myTransformation);`  `myTransformation.getAlpha();`: https://sourcegraph.com/android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/-/info/JavaArtifact/AndroidSDK/-/android/view/animation/Transformation:type/getAlpha

Comment: Thanks, but what is getDrawingTime()? Compiler cannot resolve this method.

Comment: Try adding a new class `Transformation.java` as seen here: https://sourcegraph.com/android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/-/blob/core/java/android/view/animation/Transformation.java Then follow the just first example in: https://sourcegraph.com/android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/-/info/JavaArtifact/AndroidSDK/-/android/view/animation/Transformation:type/getAlpha

Comment: Got it. Method was dedicated to view, so myView.getDrawingTime() solved it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Are you able to solve your original question? :-)

Comment: Yes, it's now returning correct values. If you can provide some short answer to this post, I can accept it (for example your first comment). :)

Comment: Thank you. :-) Cheers to new knowledge!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `Transformation` with your `AlphaAnimation`, you may be able to retrieve alpha value directly from your `AlphaAnimation` object instead of your `View`.

Purpose of using Transformation:

> Defines the transformation to be applied at one point in time of an Animation.

---

**Steps:**

1. Create a new `Transformation.java` class as shown in https://sourcegraph.com/android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/-/blob/core/java/android/view/animation/Transformation.java.
2. Initialize a `Transformation` object:

   ```
   private Transformation myTransformation;
   mTransformation = new Transformation();
   ```
3. Using your code:

   ```
   Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
   fadeOut.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
   fadeOut.setDuration(350);
   ```
4. Get the time at which the drawing of the view hierarchy started (in milliseconds):

   ```
   final long time = myView.getDrawingTime();
   ```
5. Get the transformation to apply at a specified point in time. Finally, obtain the actual alpha value during the animation:

   ```
   fadeOut.getTransformation(time, myTransformation);
   final float myAlphaValue = myTransformation.getAlpha();
   ```

---

*Resources*:
https://sourcegraph.com/android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/-/blob/core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#L1699
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Transformation.html

Comment: Hello, the link from step 1 is not available. Do you still have a working one or a solution of the same issue? Thank you in advance

Comment: @user2805346 Here you go: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-2.1_r2.1s/core/java/android/view/animation/Transformation.java